# Safari trouble positioning SVG feSpotlight filter

Tags: svg, safari, svg-filters

I want to use a spotlight effect but it only seems to work in Chrome, looks "just ok" in Firefox, but will not position (x,y,z) in Safari. (Other browsers not tested)

I've tried different filter and primitive units, and while this makes a difference, Safari still cannot seem to position the lighting effect in any case.

In pursuit of understanding what is going on, I've tried lots of workarounds including different userSpaceOnUse/objectBoundingBox combos, and different svg structure but have never been able to find one that works on Safari.

#### Examples

Default filter/primitive units:
https://jsfiddle.net/localnerve/y470d52v/

objectBoundingBox units:
https://jsfiddle.net/localnerve/uyc7o52k/

A picture is also worth a 1000 words (Safari, Chrome, FF). The spotlight on Safari is rendered off-canvas to the right and bleeds in from the right.

[image: LTR: Safari, Chrome, and Firefox showing the spotlight]

To show the spotlight positions on Safari are "out of whack", here's me nudging them in web inspector so I can see the spotlight render at all:

[image]

Here is the code using objectBoundingBox filter and primitive units:

```
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  * {
    transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
  }
  .scene-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .scene-container.content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(hsla(240, 90%, 8%, 1) 0%, 99%, hsla(217,24%,71%,0) 100%);
    box-shadow: 0px -10px 20px hsl(240, 90%, 8%);
  }
  .spot {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>

<body>
<div class="scene-container content">
  <h2>Here's a spotlight.</h2>
  <svg class="spot" viewBox="0 0 2000 3000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
    <defs>
      <filter x="-0.2" y="-0.2" width="1.4" height="1.4" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="spotlight">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="8" result="blur1"></feGaussianBlur>
        <feSpecularLighting result="specOut" in="blur1" specularConstant="1.8" specularExponent="5" lighting-color="#ffffff">
          <feSpotLight x="0.5" y="-0.4" z="0.03" pointsAtX="0.5" pointsAtY="0.8" pointsAtZ="0" limitingConeAngle="13.7"></feSpotLight>
        </feSpecularLighting>
        <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="specOut" operator="arithmetic" k1="0" k2="1" k3="1" k4="0"></feComposite>
      </filter>
      <clipPath id="spot-clip">
        <rect x="-50" y="2840" width="2200" height="200"></rect>
      </clipPath>
      <filter id="spot-blur">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="15">
        </feGaussianBlur>
      </filter>
    </defs>
    <g transform="translate(0, -175)" filter="url(#spotlight)">
      <ellipse cx="50%" cy="95.333%" rx="27%" ry="130" fill="#fff" clip-path="url(#spot-clip)" filter="url(#spot-blur)"></ellipse>
      <rect x="25%" y="43.667%" width="50%" height="50%" stroke="peru" stroke-width="3%" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="#000"></rect>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
</body>
```

Any insight you can give is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does meh in Firefox mean?

Comment: Oh sorry, that was just meant to mean that the spotlight looks just OK. The combined filter lighting effects just don't look good. I'll correct the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are known bugs in webkit/Safari for light source positioning wrt transforms and oBB units. After the webkit/blink engine schism, no-one at Apple picked these bugs up from the Chrome team.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=88877
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=113059

The workaround is not to use transforms and oBB units (do any dynamic positioning or sizing via JavaScript)

Comment: Thank you very much for this response, you provided excellent info/evidence with concision. My initial experiments show no straight-forward rules work on all DPRs/Viewports/Zooms and JS devolves into lots of conditionals I don't want to own over time. In my case, I may just have a graphics program generate an image for safari only - I'd rather own that. Disappointing such sad corners of the web still exist (and will likely persist). Regardless, thank you again!

Comment: Yes, sadly there is a bunch of SVG 1.1 that was never fully implemented (particularly around text) and the browser teams have very few people working on it.

Comment: It seems these bugs are now marked as fixed in WebKit - updated Alex's bug report to "SVG Weirdness" here with some details: https://github.com/emilbjorklund/svg-weirdness/issues/31